# Add Migration adding multiple foreign keys in the dependent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
abstract class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DId { get; set; }
    public D D {get; set}
}

class B : A
{

}

class C : A
{

}

class D
{
    public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
```

Migration file:

```
CreateTable(
            "A",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true)
                Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false,maxLength: 128),
                DId = c.Long(),
                DId_Id1 = c.Long(),
                DId_Id2 = c.Long()
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("A", t => t.DId_Id1)
            .ForeignKey("A", t => t.DId_Id2)
            .ForeignKey("A", t => t.DId)
            .Index(t => t.DId)
            .Index(t => t.DId_Id1)
            .Index(t => t.DId_Id2);
```

when i add the migration, ef creating three foreign key columns with indexes. Is the right of way of doing table per hierarchy with one to many relationship

Comment: Could you provide more detail - how many and what are they?

Comment: I suggest you look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) on inheritance and EF

Comment: That migration created exactly what your model requires.  A D can have 1 or more A's, one or more B's and one or more C's.